# Mongodb select information to get from an object without knowing object key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have this documents at my DB

```
{
"_id":"606b583b2506eb000988a8fd",
"lastSync":"2021-04-13T00:10:02.984+00:00",
"Month":{
    "2020-12":{
      "a":10,
      "b":21
    },
    "2021-01":{
      "a":112,
      "b":34
    },
    "2021-03":{
      "a":35,
      "b":56
    },
    "2021-02":{
      "a":767,
      "b":56
    },
    "2021-04":{
     "a":78,
     "b":98
   }
}
}
```

How can I query something like db.collection.agreggate(query) and get as answer an array like:

```
[
"2020-12":{
"a":10},
"2021-01":{
"a":112},...]
```

Have already tried agregation methods with $project but just could not find the kind of object I wanted

Comment: Do you display only `a` values or `b` also?

Comment: i want only a objects

Comment: Please include valid JSON for your starting BSON document (what you have shown above is not valid JSON).

Comment: Done, Valid json included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/v5My6yjrIC0

[$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

[$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

[$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

[$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      "newRoot": {
        $arrayToObject: { // convert array to object
          $map: { // loop over each item in an array and returns an array
            "input": { $objectToArray: "$Month"}, // convert to array
            "as": "el",
            "in": { k: "$$el.k", v: { a: "$$el.v.a" } // shape the data
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

If you want everything inside Month check this demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/lD0wPTc_W4Y

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      "newRoot": "$Month"
    }
  }
])
```